# Infinite loop issue when Iterating List of Maps

Tags: java

My below code causing infinite loop. I am adding 3 `maps` to the `ArrayList` and tried to Iterate the `list` of `Maps`. But I don't know what causing the infinite loop. I know I might did some silly mistake, but I couldn't figure it out. Can anyone help ?

```
package paddy.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Maptest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Map < String, Integer > m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        m.put("a", 1);
        m.put("b", 1);
        m.put("c", 1);
        m.put("d", 1);
        m.put("e", 1);

        Map < String, Integer > m1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        m1.put("a", 1);
        m1.put("b", 1);
        m1.put("c", 1);
        m1.put("d", 1);
        m1.put("e", 1);

        Map < String, Integer > m2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        m2.put("a", 1);
        m2.put("b", 1);
        m2.put("c", 1);
        m2.put("d", 1);
        m2.put("e", 1);

        List<Map<String, Integer>> lm = new ArrayList<>();

        lm.add(m);
        lm.add(m1);
        lm.add(m2);

        Iterator<Map<String, Integer>> lmItr = lm.iterator();

        while (lmItr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `lmItr.hasNext()` doesn't advance the iterator. `lmItr.next()` does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't consuming your iterator, instead you are printing a constant. Change

```
while (lmItr.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(1);
}
```

to

```
while (lmItr.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(lmItr.next());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didnt know that `lmItr.hasNext()` doesnt advance the iterator since I am pretty new to Java.

Comment: also you can iterate with lm.forEach(curMap -> curMap.forEach((s, integer) -> System.out.println(s + ":" + integer)));